# Struct vs map in protobuf

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, proto

I am trying to create a field in protobuf so that client can pass in arbitrary key value so that server can read that field. I know there are map and struct in protobuf but I don't see the difference of these two. Any insights? Both client and server are in python

Comment: AFAIK, a struct is basically a map with defined keys

Comment: @OneCricketeer I don't think so. As in https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated#struct, we can use arbitrary keys in struct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A struct is strictly defined as a `map<string, Value>`, mapping to [`Value`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.Value) types, e.g. a (simple) Python class definition

A Protobuf [map](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/proto3-spec#map_field) can support more than only string keys, e.g. a `dict`

Comment: I see. But when I use `map<string, google.protobuf.Any> extras`, somehow. `extras.update()` gives me error of `Direct assignment of submessage not allowed`. Not sure if it is related to the `google.protobuf.Any`? The value I used is a python `List`

Comment: Are you able to have `map<string, ListValue>`?

Comment: I want to make the value type arbitrary so other people can pass in different key value pair.

Comment: "Value represents a dynamically typed value which can be either null, a number, a string, a boolean, a recursive struct value, or a list of values", which excludes a few Any types